# Why does these curves are different at the origin.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ be given by $\alpha(t)= (t^3,t^2)$. The trace of $\alpha$ is drawn below:

[image]

Since $\alpha'(t)=(3t^2,2t)$, we have in $t=0$: $\alpha (0)=(0,0)$ and $\alpha'(0)=(0,0)$, then at the origin the tangent vector is zero.

Now let $\beta:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2 $ be given by $\beta(t)=(t,|t|)$. The trace of $\beta$ is drawn below:

[image]

Note that $\beta(0)=(0,0)$ and the curve is not differentiable at this point (we can see this by elementary calculus).

I would like to know intuitively why these curves are so different at the origin, for me they are pretty much the same (a corner).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the difference, don't look in $(0,0)$ (that's just one point and it cannot tell you anything about the local behavior), but look in a neighborhood, at points where $|t|$ is small.

If $t$ is small, the tangent to $\alpha$ is $(3t^2,2t)$ while the tangent to $\beta$ is $(1,\pm 1)$. As $t$ goes to $0$ we have that $3t^2$ is much smaller than $1$ so the horizontal part of the tangent vector to $\alpha$ goes to zero faster than the horizontal part of $\beta$. But the tangent vector shows the direction in which the curve "goes" at time $t$. Intuitively we see that for $t$ very small $\alpha$'s tangent vector is almost vertical. That's why the curve $\alpha$ gets into $(0,0)$ vertically and the curve $\beta$ gets into $(0,0)$ with an angle.